# Faster RCNN transfer learning Keras

Tags: python, keras, faster-rcnn

I have implemented with my own custom dataset a faster RCNN in Keras following this very useful guide:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/a-practical-implementation-of-the-faster-r-cnn-algorithm-for-object-detection-part-2-with-cac45dada619

I would like to ask you some details in that implementation for those of you that already had a similar experience on that:

Once I the code is running the compiler returns: "Could not load pretrained model weights. Weights can be found in the keras application folder \https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/keras/applications", **Does it mean that I not exploiting transfer learning?**

Do you know something on that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the basic of transfer learning is using pretrained models to train new labels, based on the error message you should download the pretrained models and retrain your that models with your new labels